# Want to read multiple csv file one by one and filepaths are stored in a text file using python

Tags: python, csv

here is my code for readinng individual cell of one csv file. but want to read multiple csv file one by one from .txt file where csv file paths are located.

```
import csv

ifile = open ("C:\Users\BKA4ABT\Desktop\Test_Specification\RDBI.csv", "rb")

data = list(csv.reader(ifile, delimiter = ';'))
REQ = []
RES = []

n = len(data)
for i in range(n):

    x = data[i][1]
    y = data[i][2]
    REQ.append (x)
    RES.append (y)
    i += 1
for j in range(2,n):
    try:
        if REQ[j] != '' and RES[j]!= '': # ignore blank cell

            print REQ[j], '  ', RES[j]  


    except:
        pass
    j += 1
```

And csv file paths are stored in a .txt file like

```
C:\Desktop\Test_Specification\RDBI.csv

C:\Desktop\Test_Specification\ECUreset.csv
C:\Desktop\Test_Specification\RDTC.csv
and so on..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read stuff stored in files into variables. And you can use variables with strings in them anywhere you can use a literal string. So...

```
with open('mytxtfile.txt', 'r') as txt_file:
    for line in txt_file:
        file_name = line.strip() # or was it trim()? I keep mixing them up
        ifile = open(file_name, 'rb')
        # ... the rest of your code goes here
```

Maybe we can fix this up a little...

```
import csv
with open('mytxtfile.txt', 'r') as txt_file:
    for line in txt_file:
        file_name = line.strip()
        csv_file = csv.reader(open(file_name, 'rb', delimiter=';'))
        for record in csv_file[1:]: # skip header row
            req = record[1]
            res = record[2]
            if len(req + res):
                print req, '   ', res
```

Comment: @Daren Thomas Thank you for your quick reply, i have tried but it read only first file, i want to read all files one by one, how can i iterate this loop?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add a while which will read your file containing your list of files & paths upon your first open statement, for example

```
from __future__ import with_statement

with open("myfile_which_contains_file_path.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        ifile = open(line, 'rb')
        # here the rest of your code
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,  i am getting error SyntaxError:   from __future__ import must occur at the begining of the file

Comment: try it by dropping the `from __future__ ...`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a raw string string your path contains `\`

```
import csv

file_list = r"C:\Users\BKA4ABT\Desktop\Test_Specification\RDBI.csv"
with open(file_list) as f:
   for line in f:
       with open(line.strip(), 'rb') as the_file:
           reader = csv.reader(the_file, delimiter=';')
           for row in reader:
               req,res = row[1:3]
               if req and res:
                   print('{0} {1}'.format(req, res))
```